# Help setting up reverse lookup with BIND9

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

First off, I'm still a newbie when it comes to Ubuntu. I would appreciate if someone could show me what I'm doing wrong. I have a Windows 10 machine as my main machine, and I run two VMs with VMWare, one of them is Ubuntu server, and the other is Ubuntu client. I've managed to successfully set up the DHCP server so far. I'm stuck with setting up the DNS server, I managed to get the hostname nslookup (i.e. ns1) to work correctly, however, I have NOT been able to get the nslookup 192.168.1.3 (i.e IP address) to work correctly. Here is what is currently in my settings:

named.conf.local:

```
//The following code defines the forward lookup zone.
zone “group2.lab” {
type master;
file “/etc/bind/zones/group2.lab.db”;
};

//The following code defines the reverse lookup zone.  
zone “1.168.192.in-addr.arpa” {
type master;
file “/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa”;
};
```

group2.lab.db:

```
$TTL 86400
@      IN   SOA   group2.lab. root (
          2 ; serial
          28800 ; refresh
          14400 ; retry
          3600000 ; expire
          86400 ; ttl
          )
       IN   NS    192.168.1.3.
       IN   MX    10  group2.lab.
ns1    IN   A     192.168.1.3
www    IN   CNAME ns1
```

rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa:

```
$TTL 86400
@           IN    SOA    group2.lab.  root (
              2009031001 ; serial
          28800 ; refresh
          14400 ; retry
          3600000 ; expire
          86400 ; ttl
          )
        IN    NS    192.168.1.3.
1           IN    PTR   ns1.group2.lab.
```

resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.3
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search group2.lab
```

hostname:

```
ubuntu
```

hosts:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      ubuntu
192.168.1.3    ns1.group2.lab ns1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This is what I see when I attempt an nslookup:

```
root@ubuntu:~# nslookup ns1
Server: 192.168.1.3
Address:    192.168.1.3#53

Name:   ns1.group2.lab
Address:    192.168.1.3

root@ubuntu:~# nslookup 192.168.1.3
Server: 192.168.1.3
Address:    192.168.1.3#53

** server can't find 3.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa:

```
$TTL 86400
@           IN    SOA    group2.lab.  root (
              2009031001 ; serial
          28800 ; refresh
          14400 ; retry
          3600000 ; expire
          86400 ; ttl
          )
        IN    NS    192.168.1.3.
1           IN    PTR   ns1.group2.lab.
```

should be:

```
$TTL 86400
@           IN    SOA    group2.lab.  root (
              2009031001 ; serial
          28800 ; refresh
          14400 ; retry
          3600000 ; expire
          86400 ; ttl
          )
        IN    NS    192.168.1.3.
3           IN    PTR   ns1.group2.lab.
```

Thanks for at least taking a look guys, after spending countless hours/days on this, I figured it out...the 1 should've been a 3 :).

Comment: I appreciate this was asked a while ago but could you (or anyone else) explain why 1 should have been 3 and what this signifies -- for future readers.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter The IP address in this example was `192.168.1.3`. The reverse lookup zone uses the first 3 octets in reverse order: `1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`. Using the last octet of the the IP address (`3`) in the zone file for the PTR record solved the issue of the OP.